# Change Text of button in jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few buttons each with a specific class to differentiate it from other similar buttons. Class name follows the format `moreid` where `id` changes with button. I am using following code to change button text:

```
function changeText(btn){
  $('.'+btn).text(function(i, text){
    return text === "Show More" ? "Show Less" : "Show More";}
)}
```

I call this function using `changeText(moreid)`. With this code I get the error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .[object HTMLDivElement]
```

This is the HTML of button

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-primary btn-lg moreapple" 
        data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target="#moreapple" 
        onclick="changeText(moreapple)">Show More</button>
```

The only thing that change from one button to another is moreapple to morenews etc.

How can I change this function to change button text?

Comment: Show us your html code, also, how are you calling that function? Which is the  param?

Comment: need the html code as well. your code works fine. try this http://jsfiddle.net/re0218gg/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/emzuk1um/

Comment: @leo.fcx and Sushil I have added the HTML code.

Comment: you should be passing `changeText('moreapple')` instead of `changeText(moreapple)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `changeText(btn)` tells that, you're passing `btn` as an argument, so you might have to give this a try

```
$(btn).text(function(i, text){
    return text === "Show More" ? "Show Less" : "Show More";
});
```

Your markup should be like this unless you've specific requirements

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-primary btn-lg moreapple" 
        data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target="#moreapple" 
        onclick="changeText(this)">Show More</button>
```

use `$(btn)` as it comes from the calling function
`changeText()`

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/bx77k4b7/)

Comment: is `btn` used because of the class name `btn`?

Comment: @SujataHulsurkar It's a good practice to pass `this` if you want to target clicked element rather than class name, because in DOM there will be many elements having the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your Id's would be different depending on your naming convention
[Duplicate Question Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735726/show-more-less-text-with-just-html-and-javascript)

```
var status = "less";

function toggleText()
{
    var text="Here is some text that I want added to the HTML file";

    if (status == "less") {
        document.getElementById("textArea").innerHTML=text;
        document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerText = "See Less";
        status = "more";
    } else if (status == "more") {
        document.getElementById("textArea").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerText = "See More";
        status = "less"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your markup from

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-primary btn-lg moreapple" 
        data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target="#moreapple" 
        onclick="changeText(moreapple)">Show More</button>
```

to

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-primary btn-lg moreapple" 
        data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target="#moreapple" 
        onclick="changeText('moreapple')">Show More</button> <!-- Pass moreapple as string -->
```