# how can i split some lines of text body in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this text :

> Mount Kosciuszko is mainland Australia's highest mountain, at 2,228
> metres above sea level. It is located on the Main Range of the Snowy
> Mountains in Kosciuszko National Park, part of the Australian Alps
> National Parks and Reserves in New South Wales.

I gonna show just a line of the above content, for more information user must click on the more button, how can I do this?
data coming from API  and I don't want to add CSS styles like display ane etc, it possible with javascript function? I mean like strpos, trim and other stuff just like PHP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [show more/Less text with just HTML and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735726/show-more-less-text-with-just-html-and-javascript)

Comment: @KaanCetinkaya it wasn't my answer, I want to cut some of the text lines, for instance, I want to display up from 0 to 200 characters, and  the rest of it doesn't display

Comment: The answer was text.substring(0,100)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general algorithm to show more and less activity

a live demo is here: https://repl.it/join/uptshekb-kaancetinkayasf

Code:

Html file

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  
  </head>
  <body>
    <p1 id="text"></p1>
  <button id="show">Show More</button>
  <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Js File

```
const display = document.getElementById('text');
const button = document.getElementById('show');

let text = "Mount Kosciuszko is mainland Australia's highest mountain, at 2,228 metres above sea level. It is located on the Main Range of the Snowy Mountains in Kosciuszko National Park, part of the Australian Alps National Parks and Reserves in New South Wales."

let showingMore = false;
let newArr = [];

function moreLess(){
  let arr=[];
if(text.length>50){
  
  for(let i=0;i<50;i++){
    arr.push(text[i]);
  }
   newArr=arr.join('');
}
display.innerText = newArr;
}

function showMore(){
  if(showingMore==true){
    display.innerText = newArr;
    showingMore=false;  
    return;
  }
  if(showingMore==false){
    display.innerText = text;
    showingMore=true;  
    return;
  }

  }

moreLess();

button.addEventListener('click',showMore);
```